# URL rewrite doesn't rewrite page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I tried to use th URL Rewrite module, but it won't rewrite the URL for some reason. If I go to this website: `http://localhost/projectredrum/foto.php` it will show the correct page, but it doesn't rewrite the URL to what I want.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /projectredrum/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^foto\.php$ /Aquaria-Foto/Fotos
</IfModule>
```

1. [Rewrite Module Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oqg6Chk6L7M)

After looking at the tutorial mentioned above I figured I should try without

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Because if you use this, it will only rewrite the URL when the URL doesn't match a file name or directory.

However when I did that I got a `404 page not found` issue.

Does anyone know why the URL rewrite doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working because of this condition:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

since `http://localhost/projectredrum/foto.php` is a valid file.

To fix the rule you can use this in `/projectredrum/.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /projectredrum/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /foto\.php[?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /Aquaria-Foto/Fotos [L,NC,R=302]
```

`R=302` is used to actually redirect the URL in browser.

In `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` you can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^Aquaria-Foto/Fotos/?$ /projectredrum/foto.php [L,NC]
```

#### References:

- [Apache mod_rewrite Introduction](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/tech.html)
- [Apache mod_rewrite In-Depth Details](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708)

Comment: I've replaced my code with yours, but I'm getting a 404 page not found error, just like I was before

Comment: No sir, these are the only rules & the .htaccess is placed directly in the main directory which is projectredrum

Comment: Cool, it redirects now, but it redirects to page 404, could you help me figure out why it redirects to a page 404?

Comment: That's correct sir, I get `http://localhost/Aquaria-Foto/Fotos` in the browser, and I do want to show the content of `http://localhost/Aquaria-Foto/Fotos`

Comment: Alright I've just implemented your updated answer, however I'am still getting a `404 page not found error`

Comment: If I type in something random, I get a 500 server error so htaccess is working, the URL producing the 404 page not found error is: http://localhost/Aquaria-Foto/Fotos

Comment: I think I've placed my htaccess file on the wrong place, At this moment I have one in the directory: `projectredrum` where do you want me to place the second file?

/projectredrum/.htaccess <- this is where one of the files is
DocumentRoot/.htaccess <- with `DocumentRoot` do you mean the map in which my LocalHost is located?

Comment: I have placed the secondary .htaccess in a directory above projectredrum but it doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69305/discussion-between-anubhava-and-gerwin).

Answer (score 2):

Apache does local rewrite, because page is in same server it can load it on same request. Add `[R,L]` to end of RewriteRule line to rediret browser to wanted address.

R means temporally Redirect,
L means last rule.
R=301 is permanent redirect
eg `[R=301,L]` does permanent redirect and stops checking other rules.

In your case, you probably want to use this kind line:

`RewriteRule ^foto\.php$ /Aquaria-Foto/Fotos [R,L]`

Here is more info about flags: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html